# Connecting to MySQL in SNAP(nextcloud) with python

Tags: python, mysql, snap

Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Nextcloud server installed with Snap(https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap).

I need to connect to Nextcloud MySQL DB inside Snap and make SELECT on some tables, but I don't understand how to do it with python.

If I'm using standard CLI utility, everything is fine.

```
sudo nextcloud.mysql-client -S /tmp/sockets/mysql.sock
```

But I don't understand how to do the same thing with python and dedicated MySQL user.

I've tried to use '**subprocess.check_output**' route, but it turns out to be a terrible idea...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Snap stores the `/tmp` directory under:

```
/tmp/snap-private-tmp/
```

So the socket you're looking for there is actually under:

```
/tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.nextcloud/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Or on 22.04 LTS, `mysqlx.sock`

However you can't actually **use this socket** file to connect to connect to the Nextcloud instance because of the way Snap's sandboxing works.

```
mysql -S ./mysqlx.sock
ERROR:
```

I think the best workaround is probably:

1. Re-build the nextcloud-snap to use TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 for access to MySQL
2. Migrate from the snap based deployment to traditional deployment.

Personally, when I first started using Linux around 25 years ago this book was one of the first ones that I read and really liked:

[image]

Note the Subtitle: **Making Easy Things Easy & Hard Things Possible**

In my limited experience working with `snap`, it consistently **makes easy things hard**, and it completely diverges from everything else that I understand about Linux in it's own extremely proprietary way.

If I must deal with a container, `docker` is far less troublesome. I expect `Ubuntu LTS` as a common server standard will eventually be undone by their instance on `snap`.